# reading java class output from batch

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm trying to capture the output of several java classes by calling them and then parsing or echoing their output from a batch command program.

I've used the format:

```
for /f "delims=" %i IN ('java -classpath "%javapaths%" arg1 arg2 arg3') do (set output=%%i)
echo %output%
```

Note: based on a post for this exact question on here, one user suggested appending the output in the for loop which I tried with no success. In my case the java output is always 1 line.

What's odd is that it appears the java is executing and the output is written to the command prompt when called, instead of passing the output to the %i variable. So what happens above is that the java runs and provides the response and then the echo runs and just says "Echo is off."

Does this have to do with the version of batch I am using? I don't understand why I can run VB scripts this way and successfully capture the output no problem using the cscript command inside a for loop.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using `log4j` or a similar Java logging framework?

Comment: There is a percent missing in the first `%i`, it should be `%%i`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen log4j is being used, but I'm not experienced with java. I know it creates a log file with error outputs, but it doesn't for successful outputs.

Comment: @Aacini I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @Aacini sorry, that is a typo above and you are correct. I am using %%i